# Laravel won't store values defined by offsetSet()

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code

```
class DonorsController extends Controller
{
    //Some code

    public function donorAddSave(Request $request){
      if ($request->file('DonorPhoto')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
        $DonorPhotoURL = date_timestamp_get(date_create()).'.'.$request->file('DonorPhoto')->guessExtension();
        $request->file('DonorPhoto')->move($destinationPath,$DonorPhotoURL);
      }

      $request->offsetSet('UserID',1);
      $request->offsetSet('DonorPhotoURL','/'.$destinationPath.'/'.$DonorPhotoURL);

      if(!$request->has('DonorPrefix')){
        $request->offsetSet('DonorPrefix', 'Mx.');
      }

      $donor = \App\Donor::create($request->all());
      return redirect('/donor/'.$donor->DonorID);
    }
}
```

When I tried `return $request->all()` to see whether the value of `DonorPrefix`, `UserID`, and `DonorPhotoURL` has been stored in the array of requests or not, the returned JSON seems to have all of these three variables.

```
{
"DonorCitizenID": "1000000000000",
"DonorPrefix": "คุณ",
...
"UserID": 1,
"DonorPhotoURL": "/uploads/1465963777.png",
"DonorPhoto": {}
}
```

But when I tried return `$donor`, which is the object of the Donor, defined its value by the `$donor = \App\Donor::create($requests->all());`, the value of `UserID` and `DonorPhotoURL` is NOT stored, but the `DonorPrefix` does have the value of `Mx`. Here are the JSON for `$donor`:

```
{
"DonorCitizenID": "1000000000000",
"DonorPrefix": "คุณ",
...
"updated_at": "2016-06-15 04:16:47.000",
"created_at": "2016-06-15 04:16:47.000",
"DonorID": 39
}
```

(The `...` represents some data omnitted for cleaner snippet)

I am sure the database itself has the column name of `DonorPhotoURL` and `UserID`, but it doesn't still store the values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `App\Donor` model has the field in `$fillable` in order for [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) to work.